# Set content body of httpresponse?

Tags: c#, class, httpresponse

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx

How do I set the content in the body?

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "message":"response content example"
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Output` and `OutputStream` properties, or the `Write` method.

Answer (score 5):

```
myHttpResponse.Write("\"{\"message\":\"response content example\"}\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

In AspNetCore:

`await context.Response.WriteJsonAsync("\"{\"message\":\"response content example\"}\"");`

Or using a dynamic object:

`await context.Response.WriteJsonAsync(new { message = "response content example" });`